# Optimizing SQL Query for mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I just changed from Access to mySQL. I have a few tables, called "Veranstaltung" and "Veranstaltung_User". I want to get all events (=Veranstaltung) to which users have subsribed, exept the one, the user is viewing.

I did this with the following statment

```
SELECT VID, Bezeichnung, Datum 
FROM tbl_Veranstaltung 
WHERE year(Datum) = 2012 
    AND VID <> 613 
    AND VID IN (SELECT BewerbID 
                FROM Veranstaltung_User 
                WHERE UserID IN (SELECT UserID 
                                FROM Veranstaltung_User 
                                WHERE BewerbID = 613) 
                    AND UserID <> 0) 
ORDER BY Datum
```

In Access, this query was quite fast - in mySQL it needs 44,56 seconds - too much ;-)

how can I optimize my statement for faster quering? (mySQL > 5, tables ware MyISAM)

thanks for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two changes:
1. Uses JOINs instead of nested IN clauses
2. Uses `<= and >` instead of the `YEAR()` function

The advantage of change `1` is that sometime IN performance can be worse than expected, and nesting them will exascerabate that.

The advantage of change `2` is that it allows an index seek to find a range of records.  Where-as using YEAR() forcfes a scan of the entire table/index.

Both of which assume you have appropriate indexes.

```
SELECT
  V.VID, V.Bezeichnung, V.Datum
FROM
  tbl_Veranstaltung     V
INNER JOIN
  Veranstaltung_User    VUser
    ON VUser.BewerbID = V.VID
INNER JOIN
  Veranstaltung_User    VUser2
    VUser.UserID = VUser2.UserID
WHERE
      V.Datum >= '20120101'
  AND V.Datum <  '20130101'
  AND V.VID <> 613
  AND VUser.UserID <> 0
  AND VUser2.BewerbID  = 613
ORDER BY
  Datum
```

Answer (score 0):

This query may need adjusting, have tried to make some assumptions as to table layout + will update based on any clarification offered

```
SELECT 
    v.VID, 
    v.Bezeichnung, 
    v.Datum 

FROM tbl_Veranstaltung AS v

INNER JOIN Veranstaltung_User AS vu
ON vu.BewerbID = v.VID
AND vu.UserID = [THIS USER ID]
AND vu.BewerbID <> 613

// Used a BETWEEN so that MySQL does not need to apply YEAR() to every row
WHERE v.Datum BETWEEN DATE('2012-01-01') AND DATE('2012-12-30');
```

I would also advise the following two indexes

```
CREATE INDEX dateIndex ON tbl_Veranstaltung (`Datum`);
CREATE INDEX userBewerIndex ON Veranstaltung_User (`BewerbID`,`UserID`);
```

Following that the query should be practically instant by comparison

**Edit** If I take the source query verbatim I would use the following

```
SELECT 
    v.VID, 
    v.Bezeichnung, 
    v.Datum 

FROM tbl_Veranstaltung AS v

INNER JOIN Veranstaltung_User AS vu
ON vu.BewerbID = v.VID
AND vu.BewerbID <> 613
AND vu.UserID <> 0

WHERE v.Datum BETWEEN DATE('2012-01-01') AND DATE('2012-12-30');
```